# During instantiation of a class how to check if an object of that class already exists and if it does, point to the already existing object?

Tags: python

I was asked this question in an interview. What I tried to do was as follows:

```
class A:
    l = []
    def __init__(self):
        if len(A.l)==0:
            A.l.append(self)
        else:
            return A.l[0]

a = A()
b = A()
```

I came home and ran this code and understood that it won't work.

So I would like to know what is the correct way to solve this problem. The expected result is that when `A()` is called for the second time, `b` should point to the object that is already stored in `a` (the first created object).

Comment: just in case anyone wanted to know, i didn't get the job.

Comment: sad to know :( Anyway there are lot of fish (I mean jobs) in the market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to implement something like Singleton. Most easier approach would be to overwrite `__new__` instead of `__init__`.